# ASM 5.0.3 JSRInlinerAdapter quickly fills code cache memory

Tags: java, assembly, jvm, java-bytecode-asm

I am facing a strange issue while instrumenting java web application using ASM 5.0.3 / Java 1.7_80 / Apache Tomcat-6.0.35.

After server started with in 1 or 2 days **code cache memory** is completely filled 100% and never Garbage collected. Same is verified without Instrumentation which is working fine & code cache never fills 100%

I am using "**JSRInlinerAdapter**" in my instrumentation code. Since my application contains all class file versions from **48 to 51** (1.4 to 1.7)

My question is - Is **code cache** memory filled with inline methods when JIT compiler compiles these methods? (since i use *JSRInlinerAdapter*) ?

**Additional info**

I am using following VM arguments

```
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true 
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing 
-Djsse.enableCBCProtection=false 
-XX:NewSize=384m 
-XX:MaxNewSize=384m 
-XX:PermSize=384m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m 
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=400 
-XX:MaxGCMinorPauseMillis=100 
-XX:+UseG1GC 
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
-XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark 
-XX:+UseTLAB -XX:NewRatio=3 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30 
-XX:ConcGCThreads=5 
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=20 
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods 
-XX:+UseAdaptiveGCBoundary 
-XX:+UseStringCache 
-XX:+AggressiveOpts 
-Xms1536m 
-Xmx1536m
```

What could be the reason to fill **code cache** quickly?

Comment: Don’t use `-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true`. If you have a broken comparator, fix that comparator. Otherwise, you’re only fixing one symptom, but may have an arbitrary number of other, unnoticed bugs.

Comment: Besides that, *why* are you using JSRInlinerAdapter? Your rationale actually doesn’t explain anything.

Comment: Hi Holger, Thanks for your input with `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort`. Also reason to use `JSRInlinerAdapter` is , my application contains class files from version 48 to 51.

Comment: Basically, my -javaagent jar is like a profiler. I inject some byte code to all methods in a class (using AdviceAdapter) to find the method execution time. As i have seen class file version < =49 contains JSR / RET instruction , that could cause any issue while stackmap verification. This is the reason to use `JSRInlinerAdapter'.

Comment: If the class file has a version `<= 49`, there is no stackmap verification and, unless your injected code really needs new bytecode features, the best option is to keep the version number as-is and (as always when instrumenting) touch as little code as possible.